# ORACLE Function Index not Updating

Tags: oracle, function, indexing

I've used a Function Based index to be able to sort one table based on a lookup value from another table.

It's not working if the value looked up changes - have I used a deterministic function wrongly? How else can I index a sort of one table based on the values from another?

It's Standard Edition so I only have B-tree indexes.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do this with B-tree indexes. Deterministic means that the result of the function is only depending on the input data - and the fact that oracle enforces deterministic function for indices is exactly that changes in another table do not change the index.

You absolutely have to use bitmap join indexes for this kind of problem.

The only other thing you could do is to save the lookup value on your base table redundantly and update the values on change of the lookup table. But that is bad db design and you should only do that if you absolutely have to.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I suspected that was the case but hoped there was a way round. Many thanks.